Mysql workbench won't start after upgrading to noble numbat
I just finished upgrading to Noble Numbat yesterday with no apparent issues apart from Mysql Workbench will not start. If i try to install:
mysql-workbench-community_8.0.36-1ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb
I get:
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (8.0.36-1ubuntu22.04) over (8.0.36-1ubuntu22.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libproj22 (>= 8.2.0); however:
  Package libproj22 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpython3.10 (>= 3.10.0); however:
  Package libpython3.10 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.4-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community

Please help.

You are now running 24.04 why are you trying to install something from 22.04? How was the upgrade done yesterday? Did you get prompted to update or did you force it?

So, I found the 8.0.38 package for Noble and tried to install it - pretty much the same result:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
mysql-workbench-community depends on libodbc2 (>= 2.3.1); however:
Package libodbc2 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libproj25 (>= 8.2.0); however:
Package libproj25 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Your mysql may also need an update. You carried all these apps over from the previous version, correct?

Good question as to why I'm installing the old version - but may need to. Yes, I upgraded from 22.04.

I ran atp update, apt upgrade and do-release-upgrade

The solution, provided by Perplexity AI, was as folllows:

Do not tell me in a comment. If you have an answer use the answer your own question feature at the bottom of the question.

The solution, provided by Perplexity AI, was as follows:
Based on the output you've provided, it seems the main issue is that MySQL Workbench can't find the libproj.so.25 library. Here are some steps to try and resolve this:
Install libproj:
text
sudo apt install libproj-dev
